# Why does scheduling of subscribe time side effects differ between Completable and Observable?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive

I am currently using Rx 1.

I have the following test case:

```
static void printThread(String format, Object... objects) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", Thread.currentThread().getName(),
            String.format(format, objects)));
}

public void testFoo() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> { printThread("callable"); return 1L;})
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
              .doOnSubscribe(() -> printThread("A"))
              .doOnSubscribe(() -> printThread("B"))
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
              .doOnSubscribe(() -> printThread("C"))
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
              .doOnSubscribe(() -> printThread("D"))
              .toBlocking()
              .subscribe();

    printThread("next!");

    Completable.fromCallable(() -> { printThread("callable"); Thread.sleep(10_000); return 1L;})
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
              .doOnSubscribe(a -> printThread("A"))
              .doOnSubscribe(a -> printThread("B"))
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
              .doOnSubscribe(a -> printThread("C"))
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
              .doOnSubscribe(a -> printThread("D"))
               .andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> printThread("E")))
               .andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> printThread("F")).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()))
               .await();
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
main D
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 C
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 B
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 A
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 callable
main next!
RxNewThreadScheduler-6 A
RxNewThreadScheduler-6 B
RxNewThreadScheduler-6 C
RxNewThreadScheduler-6 D
RxNewThreadScheduler-6 callable
RxNewThreadScheduler-6 E
RxNewThreadScheduler-7 F

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is there a difference in behavior on how the scheduling of subscribe-time side effects works between `Observable` and `Completable`?

I think what's happening is that for the observable the behaviour is produced because subscription happens in default single-threaded scheduling mode except where `subscribeOn()` is called, which is why A and B happen on the same thread but everything else happens on different threads.

But I don't understand why this behavior would be altered for a Completable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJava 1 is a bit inconsistent in this regard. The 1.x `Completable.subscribeOn` calls `onSubscribe` after the thread switch upon subscription whereas with `Observable`, the `doOnSubscribe` gets called before the thread switch to the upstream.

With RxJava 2, they are now consistent:

```
main D
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 C
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 A
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 B
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 callable
main next!
main D
RxNewThreadScheduler-4 C
RxNewThreadScheduler-5 A
RxNewThreadScheduler-5 B
RxNewThreadScheduler-6 callable
```